# javascript dialog() option error in Asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to pop up a form on click of a button. I have included

```
  <link href="../../Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js">
```

The page .

and Using ->

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#AddBook').click(function () {
            $('#form').dialog({
                height: 500,
                width: 500,
                "title": "Add Book "
            }).html();
        });
    });
  </script>
```

for the first time of click of "AddBook" button it is rendering the proper output.But ,when i click the button second time ,it shows an exception "0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'.

Comment: What is the element with `id="form"`? Post the relevant html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it more correctly as you're using MVC:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Or you can use bundling:

In BundleConfig.cs

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"
));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.*",
));
```

And usage in view:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

There is no need in callng .html() in your script.

Answer (score 0):

Its seems Your script has not been properly included. You are missing End tag `</script>`

```
<link href="../../Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js"></script>
```